# PostgreSQL - not a known variable in procedure

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I'm having trouble with writing a procedure in PostgreSQL. I can create the procedure, yet when i try to execute i get an error.The error i get

```
ERROR: "v_all_atts" is not a known variable
```

the query is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rebuild_views_with_extra_atts()
RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
v_all_atts varchar(4000);

BEGIN
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_column(p_table text, p_column text,p_category text) RETURNS VOID AS $nothing$
declare
  v_column_exists bigint := false ;
 BEGIN
 SELECT
 string_agg( CASE WHEN owner='alarm' THEN 'ai'  WHEN owner='fault' THEN 'fi' 
        END ||'.'||lower(alias) , ', '   ORDER BY owner, alias) AS string
 INTO STRICT
   v_all_atts
 FROM
   extra_attribute_cfg
 WHERE
   owner NOT LIKE 'virtual' and enable = true and v_column_exists = true;
 IF LENGTH(v_all_atts) is not null THEN
   v_all_atts := ', '||v_all_atts;
 END IF;

 v_view:= q'#
  CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW alarm_view AS
    SELECT
      fi.fault_id, ai.alarm_id, 

      #'||v_all_atts||q'#

    FROM
     alarm ai
      INNER JOIN fault fi
          ON fi.fault_id = ai.fault_id
#';
EXECUTE v_view;
END;
$nothing$ language plpgsql;

end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I have taken a long look at Postgres documentation and cannot find what is wrong and didn't find any answer to this specific situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `rebuild_views_with_extra_atts()` function is creating the `add_column()` function.

`add_column()` uses the `v_all_atts` variable, but it doesn't exist in that function, it exists only in the `rebuild_views_with_extra_atts()` function.

To resolve this, it really depends on what you're trying to do. If that variable should exist in the `add_column()` function, then declare it in there. If you're trying to use the value of `v_all_atts` when creating `add_column()` (e.g. so that the content of the function's body is dependent on the value of that variable), then you really need to use dynamic sql to generate a TEXT version of the `CREATE OR REPLACE ...` code, then EXECUTE it.